# Xcode - How to run script just before build starts

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, build, xcodebuild

I wonder if there is any way to run scripts before build starts in Xcode. There is way from

`Build phase -> Run scripts`

But this runs after the actual build is finished. I need to run script before Xcode build starts though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a build phase. Go to the project file, Build Phases, click Editor on the tool bar menu, add Build Phase, Add Run Script... **You can select and drag the script to put it before/after anything.**

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the code or assets via the script before they get compiled, just move the Run Script phase above the Compile Sources phase.